# How to have a different version of npm for a particular version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

If the requirement is to use Node.js v4.x, and npm v3.x, I was able to use

```
nvm install --lts=argon
```

to install Node v4.8.3 LTS.  But on the [Node / npm release page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), it says Node v4.8.3 comes with npm 2.15.11. And npm 3.x comes with only Node v5.x.

In this case, how can we make npm v3.x while keeping Node at version 4.x?

(and since npm v3.x can be 3.3.6 to 3.10.10, which version should be installed?)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer. It is to use `npm install` to upgrade itself:

```
npm install npm@3.10.10 -g
```

(or any version you want).